# Lagrange remainder of Taylor expansion: proof $\ge 0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How could I prove that the following is greater than or equal to $0$?
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$$

And is this series equal to:$$\frac{e^{-x}}{2}x^2$$
if yes, why?

Question related to: [Taylor expansion of $\exp(-x)$: proof tail is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343028/taylor-expansion-of-exp-x-proof-tail-is-positive)

Comment: Hint: the sum starting from $0$ is $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes i could study the function g(x)= $e^{-x}$ + x - 1, but isn't there another method? and what about the second question?

Comment: You should [link your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3343028/272831) as it is very relevant here. Presumably this question is based off of my answer, in which case you could've just asked in a comment. If you read my answer closely, it does not say it equals $e^{-x}x^2/2$ but rather $e^{-\xi}x^2/2$. My answer also mentions that the result follows from Lagrange's remainder, which you have acknowledged. So what are you asking? Are you asking for an explanation of the proof of the Lagrange remainder?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt exactly, is based on your answer. Yesterday I commented it asking explanation. Yes, your answer was strict and I would like to understand it better. Thank you very much.

Comment: It was not clear you were asking for more explanation? You should've just asked for an explanation directly.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm sorry, I have just said that i didn't understand it. Could you explain it now?

Comment: I have updated and would suggest deleting this question. If you have any more small questions, please try to ask clearly in a comment under the relevant post. If you have a major question, then perhaps you should consider posting a question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{1}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!} = e^{-x}-1+x $$
so your claim is equivalent to $e^{-x}\geq 1-x$ or $e^{z}\geq 1+z$, which holds by the convexity of $e^z$: the graph of $e^z$ lies above the graph of the tangent line at the origin.